# ¿Error de sintaxis en query al momento de utilizar la sentencia OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, h2

Buenas tardes estimados de stackoverflow.

Tengo una query que ejecuto en H2 DB:

```
SELECT T1.columnaA,T2.columnaB,T3.columnaC FROM USERS T1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_DEPT T2 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T2.USER_DEPT
INNER JOIN LOG              T3 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T3.USER_DEPT
WHERE T1.ID = '20111601'
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Necesito limitar el numero de registros a obtener de una tabla y omitir los 10 primeros. Para ello, planeo utulizar OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY al final de query:

```
SELECT T1.columnaA,T2.columnaB,T3.columnaC FROM USERS T1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_DEPT T2 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T2.USER_DEPT
INNER JOIN LOG              T3 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T3.USER_DEPT
WHERE T1.ID = '20111601'
ORDER BY T1.ID
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

Sin embargo, me marca el siguiente error:

```
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY [42000-169]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:484)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:233)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1114)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:164)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:152)
```

Un error de syntaxis al parecer, pero si omito la sentencia del OFFSET, el query me muestra de manera correcta los datos.

Ejecute este query con el OFFSET en SQLdeveloper usando Oracle 12c y se ejecuta sin problema.

Verifique el siguiente [enlace](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#select)  para validar si la clausula OFFSET es valida. Creo que podria deberse a un tema del estandar de sql que se maneja en H2 vs el de oracle 12c que un gestor funcione y otro no.

Answer (score 0):

Porque H2 no soporta esa sintáxis, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
SELECT T1.columnaA,T2.columnaB,T3.columnaC FROM USERS T1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_DEPT T2 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T2.USER_DEPT
INNER JOIN LOG              T3 ON T1.ID_DEPT = T3.USER_DEPT
WHERE T1.ID = '20111601'
ORDER BY T1.ID
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 10;
```